# Having issues with basic a basic string operation [c++, visual studio 2013]

Tags: c++, string, substring

**[RESOLVED]**
I'm reading in lines from a .txt file that stores scrambled up radio messages, not that it matters. One of the lines is called "it" and some of it's opening characters are numbers, the numbers are followed by a '/'. I'm trying to export these first few numbers into a string(called "s1")  so it can be later be used as a single integer, here's the code that is supposed to do that:

```
for (i = 0; i < it.find('/'); i++)
{
    s1[i] = it[i];
}
cout << s1;
```

but i get a string subscript range error message, what did i screw up?

**EDIT**
Issue is resolved now, thank you for helping out an absolute newbie :D My mistake was not knowing how strings work, for an actual answer from someone who understands the issue find Ben Voigt's replies. Correct code is: `s1+= it[i];`

Comment: You can't change the length of a string using `[]` (subscripting).  You can only access characters inside its existing length.  To add to the end, use one of the operations that does change length, such as `+=`, `append()`, or `resize()`.

Comment: tried the exact same but with += to no avail.

Comment: `s1 += it[i];` should have worked correctly, what error did you get?

Comment: Also, running `find('/')` on every iteration of the loop is a very clumsy approach.  Really you only need to check a single character, the one you're about to copy.

Comment: i got the exact same error message as before "string subscript out of range"

Comment: Please edit your post with an example of a few input records.

Comment: @devor: Let me guess, you tried `s1[i] += it[i];`?  But the correct version I commented above doesn't do `s1[i]`

Comment: yup i'm an idiot :D thanks for the help tho :)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely attempted to assign outside of the allocated memory for `s1`.

Assuming it and s1 are `std::string`:

```
for (auto c : it)
{
    if (c == '/')
    {
        break;
    }
    s1 += c;
}
cout << s1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the line you originally have is of the type `std::string`.

The error message "subscript out of range" basically tells that you are **trying to access a invalid position of an array**, in your case, a string. This commonly happens when the number between brackets `[ ]` is out of range of the container.

One way to avoid this type of bug is to use [iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/). By using **iterators**, you can traverse through the entire container without manually calling `operator[]`.

Consider the following code for a simple idea, this would separate the part before `/` from the original string and save it to the new variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string s = "42/fortytwo";
    std::string result = "";

    for (std::string::iterator it=s.begin(); it!=s.end(); ++it) {
        if (*it == '/') break;
        result += *it;
    }
    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

Note:

1. To use iterators, a class must have correctly implemented `* (unary operator), !=, ++, begin(), end()` operators.
2. For a more consistence usage, a [const iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/cbegin/) can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, even though i didn't understand a whole lot of it :D, anyway my problem is solved now.